# Classifying mouse gesture patterns based on time series of mouse coordinates

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, hidden-markov-model, unsupervised-learning

*Hint: I am a programmer, but not a machine-learning guy, so be patient with me ;)*

I am currently working on a side project for finding patterns in mouse movement data. Example of patterns I am interested in are the following:

[image: https://www.slideshare.net/silvanachurruca/mouse-tracking-technique-and-mouse-patterns]
*Source: https://www.slideshare.net/silvanachurruca/mouse-tracking-technique-and-mouse-patterns*

I read a lot in past time about (un)supervised learning (I know the difference), Hidden Markov Models, LSTM networks etc. I also found some working "examples", but most of them are way to theoretical and often related to find patterns in images etc.

Can some give me a hint or a (easy understandable) working example (language is not important) on finding and classifying patterns in time series data of mouse coordinates?

Comment: Please say what you mean by "working example":  a simulation?

Comment: I am looking for e.g. a python example on this task and / or a hint, how to start and what you would recommend to use.